# Updates to Laravel route file have no effect

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I am trying to create a view to display data from the database but I discovered that my route file doesn't do anything anymore.

At the moment I am trying to get the test function working but when I go to `/test` it just says **"Page not found"**. The other routes work. Even if I delete all of the contents and save the file, all the other routes work.

I have tried `artisan route:clear`, `artisan cache:clear` and so on but nothing works.

This is my route file.

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
    return "ok";
});//this is not workig

Route::get( '/', function () {
    return view( 'welcome' );
} );

Route::resource( 'submission', 'SubmissionController' );
```

Comment: Are you doing this on localhost? Remember that the paths from the routes are from the public folder - you may need some `.htaccess` to remove the public folder from the URL.

Comment: No, this is on a web server. Can you specify what do you mean by removing the public folder from the url?

Comment: Does accessing `/public/test` return "ok"?

Comment: @Qirel no, returns "page not found"

Comment: Dumb question: If it's on a server, did you uploaded the routes file to the server?

Comment: @MateiMihai Not dumb, any attempt to help is greatly appreciated. Everything was working before, the other routes still work even after i delete the route file. The other routes were created over a month ago. It seems like the route file is cached or something but whatever i do, nothing changes.

Comment: Well yes.. it seems so.. maybe delete `storage/framework/cache/*`?

Comment: Remove the slash! `Route::get('test', function () {`

Comment: @Jeemusu You are correct and I just facepalmed hard, but it still gives a 404 :(

Comment: Are there any routes above it that could be causing conflict?

Comment: @Jeemusu No, those are the only routes, tried changing the order and still nothing. Even if i delete all the routes the page still works :(

Comment: The routes must have been cached. Try removing `bootstrap/cache/routes.php` from your servers filesystem, if that works then it means your routes were cached. If you want to use route caching, then you need to run `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan route:cache` on your server every time you change your route files.

Comment: @Jeemusu cache:clear and route:cache didint do anything before but removing bootstrap/cache/routes.php Fixed it! Can you post it as an seperate answer so i could accept it and solve the question?

Comment: No problem. I added a solution. You should check the file permissions on the bootstrap directory and all it's subfolders/files. It's possible laravel doesn't have the permissions needed to alter or delete the file, hence the artisan commands having no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute `php artisan route:cache`, Laravel creates a cached routes file in the `bootstrap/cache/routes.php` directory. While this file exists all your other apps route files will be ignored.

Anytime you create new routes you will need to re-generate the routes cache by executing `php artisan route:cache`.

If you need to remove the route cache you can execute `php artisan route:clear`.

If the above fails to solve your problem, it could indicate a permissions problem. Make sure the `bootstrap/cache` directory has the correct permissions to be altered/deleted.

Failing that, you could manually delete the `bootstrap/cache/routes.php` file yourself.